# How to show PopUpMenu (VB.NET DevExpress 16.1)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, show, popupmenu

I have a PopupMenu in my code (using VB.NET and DevExpress 16.1 on Visual Studio 2015).

Here is the declaration of the menu:

```
Dim myMenu As DevExpress.Utils.Menu.DXPopupMenu = New DevExpress.Utils.Menu.DXPopupMenu()
```

And here is the Sub to show the menu:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Form1.MouseUp
    If e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        myMenu.ShowPopup(mousePosition)
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue I'm getting is: the "ShowPopup" is not recognized as a member of DevExpress.Utils.Menu.DXPopupMenu.

I looked at the documentation, it says the ShowPopup method uses the DevExpress.Utils.v17.2.dll .

Is this method available to use in v16.1 ? If not, what are the alternatives ?

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I used XtraBars instead of DXPopupMenu, added the PopupMenu to a barManager. I was then able to use the ShowPopup method.

It solved my problem.